# Holomorphic function and curve derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $\alpha:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be a $\mathcal C^1$ curve. Let $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function. Show that given $t=t_0$, $(f \circ \alpha)'(t_0)=f'(\alpha(t_0))\alpha'(t_0)$.

I could show the statement if $\alpha'(t_0) \neq 0$:

Since $\alpha'$ is continuous, there is a neighbourhood of $t_0$ where $\alpha'(t) \neq 0$. If $t$ is in that neighbourhood, by the mean value theorem one can show that $\alpha(t) \neq \alpha(t_0)$, so $$\lim_{t \to t_0} \dfrac{f(\alpha(t))-f(\alpha(t_0))}{\alpha(t)-\alpha(t_0)}$$ makes sense. But then $$\lim_{t \to t_0} \dfrac{f(\alpha(t))-f(\alpha(t_0))}{t-t_0}=\lim_{t \to t_0} \dfrac{f(\alpha(t))-f(\alpha(t_0))}{\alpha(t)-\alpha(t_0)}\dfrac{\alpha(t)-\alpha(t_0)}{t-t_0}=f'(\alpha(t_0))\alpha'(t_0).$$ From here it follows what we wanted to prove.

I don't know what to do for the case $\alpha'(t_0)=0$, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing special about $\alpha(t_0) = 0$ here.  I think your problem is to deal with $\alpha(t) = \alpha(t_0)$.  The standard proofs of the Chain Rule should be adaptable to this context.

Comment: Maybe what I meant was $\alpha'(t_0) \neq 0$, what I need is a neighbourhood of $t_0$ where $\alpha(t) \neq \alpha(t_0)$ for all $t$ in that neighbourhood.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I've made some corrections but I still got stuck in one part.

Comment: Have you looked at proofs of the Chain Rule?

Comment: And in case you missed Robert's comments: Look at the standard proofs of the chain rule! The same issue arises in the Calc 101 chain rule...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem *is* solved by the little trick that you find in the proof of the chain rule in any calculus book. I actually like a different argument better - more straightforward, no need to invent that auxiliary function.

Notation: If one says $$\phi(h)=o(h)\quad(h\to0)$$that means that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$|\phi(h)|\le\epsilon|h|\quad(|h|<\delta).$$

We can use this notation to rewrite the definition of differentiability with no division: $f$ is differentiable at $z$, with $f'(z)=D$, if and only if $$f(z+h)=f(z)+D h+o(h)\quad(h\to 0).$$

Apply the "only if" twice and then the "if" at the end:

In your situation you have
$$\begin{aligned}f(\alpha(t+h))&=f(\alpha(t)+\alpha'(t)h+o(h))
\\&=f(\alpha(t))+(\alpha'(t)h+o(h))f'(\alpha(t))+o(\alpha'(t)h+o(h))
\\&=f(\alpha(t))+\alpha'(t)f'(\alpha(t))h+o(h),\end{aligned}$$showing that $(f\circ\alpha)'(t)=\alpha'(t)f'(\alpha(t))$, at least in the unlikey event that I got the parentheses balanced.

Answer (score 0):

Because $f'(\alpha(t_0))$ exists, there is a nonnegative constant $C$ such that

$$|f(z)-f(\alpha(t_0))|\le C|z - \alpha(t_0)|$$

for $z$ close to $\alpha(t_0).$ Assuming $\alpha'(t_0)= 0,$ we then have, for $t$ close to $t_0,$

$$\left| \frac{f(\alpha(t))-f(\alpha(t_0))}{t-t_0} \right| \le  C\left |\frac{\alpha(t)-\alpha(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right| \to 0.$$